# JSON to JAVA POJO of dynamic key-value pair

Tags: java, json

I have to create POJO class of following JSON, Problem is that key p_d has variables with dynamic name like s_t, n_t, n_p and etc. the real JSON is big and i am facing problem with that part only, i shared partial JSON.
    i am using jackson for parsing.

```
{
  "flag": true,
  "flag2": false,
  "r_no": [
    {
      "room_type": 250067,
      "no_of_rooms": 1,
      "no_of_children": 1,
      "no_of_adults": 2,
      "description": "Executive Room, 1 King Bed, Non Smoking",
      "children_ages": [
        8
      ]
    },
    {
      "room_type": 250067,
      "no_of_rooms": 1,
      "no_of_children": 0,
      "no_of_adults": 2,
      "description": "Executive Room, 1 King Bed, Non Smoking"
    }
  ],
  "r_code": "abc",
  "r_key": "123",
  "p_d": {
    "s_t": [
      {
        "name": "xyz",
        "cur": "INR"
      },
      {
        "name": "xyz1",
        "cur": "INR"
      }
    ],
    "n_t": [
      {
        "name": "xyz2",
        "cur": "INR"
      }
    ],
    "n_p": [
      {
        "name": "xyz5",
        "cur": "INR"
      }
    ]
  },
  "cur": "INR"
}
```

Comment: where is your try code? @Suraj

Comment: public class PD {

@JsonProperty("s_t")
private List<ST> sT = new ArrayList<ST>();
@JsonProperty("n_t")
private List<NT> nT = new ArrayList<NT>();
@JsonProperty("n_p")
private List<NP> nP = new ArrayList<NP>();
@JsonIgnore
private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>(); setter getter}

Comment: here variable names are static but need dynamic variable.

Comment: put your code in question not in a comment edit

Answer (score 3):

For dynamic keys, use a `Map<String, Object>`:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String, Object> parsed = mapper.readValue(json, 
                                    new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {});
```

Comment: Doing same, but JSON is big and i shared only part where i am facing problem                                                                                       ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
  try {
   responseDto = mapper.readValue(response, com.HSR.class);
  } catch (JsonGenerationException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }